# How to acheive server high availbility without traffic redundancy?

Tags: high-availability

GOAL: Acheive high availability in the server side, i.e. if one link goes down the other link sends the traffic without duplication.

Explanation:
I want to achieve high availability in the servers by connecting them via PRP card to two switches. The traffic should pass between Network1 and Network2. How can I configure the router to do so without having duplicated packets? I tried the STP and LACP but I was getting duplicated traffic in network2.

Any suggested solutions is highly appreciated [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fu8d7.png)

Comment: For the curious, here's a random link about PRP: https://www.incibe-cert.es/en/blog/prp-and-hsr-redundancy-protocols .

Comment: Please include more information such as the type of switches and their configuration.  We don't have enough information to help you.